# Does SQLite choose wrong query plan when rowID is the second column of an index?

Tags: index, execution-plan, sqlite

I was testing the performance of my DB and found that SQLite wasn't choosing the right query plan for my query.

My schema:

```
CREATE TABLE event (
    ID       INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    netAddr  INTEGER             NOT NULL,
    date     INTEGER             NOT NULL,
    value    INTEGER             NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO event ( netAddr, date, value )
    WITH RECURSIVE cnt(x) as (
        VALUES(1)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT x+1 FROM cnt LIMIT 1000000
    ) SELECT 250, x, x+1000 FROM cnt;
CREATE INDEX myIdx ON event ( netAddr, ID );
```

The query:

```
SELECT value FROM event
WHERE netAddr = 250 AND ID > 100 AND ID < 110
ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;
```

It ran too slow and I inspected the query plan:

```
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN
SELECT value FROM event
WHERE netAddr = 250 AND ID > 100 AND ID < 110
ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;
```

which gave me

```
0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE event USING INDEX myIdx (netAddr=?)
```

SQLite refuses to use the second column of the index even though it is sorted the way that the query wants it to be.

Then I tested with a different index:

```
CREATE INDEX dateIdx ON event ( netAddr, date );
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN
SELECT value FROM event
WHERE netAddr = 250 AND date > 100 AND date < 110
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1;
```

which gave me

```
0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE event USING INDEX dateIdx (netAddr=? AND date>? AND date<?)
```

The query plan is now as I expect it to be.

1. Why doesn't SQLite use the whole of the index i.e. `SEARCH TABLE event USING INDEX myIdx (netAddr=? AND ID>? AND ID<?)`?
2. What is wrong with having the rowID as a second column in an index?
3. Is there a way to make it work without adding another column in the table or in the index? (I have little storage for the DB.)

EDIT:

Tried with `SELECT value FROM event WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM event WHERE netAddr = 250 AND id > 100 AND id < 110 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) LIMIT 1;` and `SELECT value FROM event WHERE netAddr = 250 AND ID > 100 AND ID < 110 ORDER BY netAddr DESC, ID DESC LIMIT 1;` as ypercubeᵀᴹ proposed - the results are the same as the "slow" query.

Tried to change the name of ID column to be something else - the results are the same.

EDIT 2:

SQLite version 3.8.2 and 3.8.8.1

Comment: Is the query slow?

Comment: For 1 million records the run time of the "slow" query (that uses myIdx(netAddr=?)) was about 0.4 secs. The "fast" query (that uses dateIdx(netAddr=? AND date>? AND date<?)) runs for 0.001 secs.
For one year I am expecting 32 million records that give me run times 13 secs vs 0.001 secs.

Comment: Can you check this query?: `SELECT value FROM event
WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM event
WHERE netAddr = 250 AND id > 100 AND id < 110
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1); `

Comment: And also your original query but changing the `ORDER BY id DESC` to: `ORDER BY netAddr DESC, id DESC`  ?

Answer (score 2):

In theory, there's nothing wrong with having the rowid as a second column in an index.
And in practice, with the current SQLite version, it works as you expected it to:

```
sqlite> .eqp on
sqlite> SELECT value FROM event
   ...> WHERE netAddr = 250 AND ID > 100 AND ID < 110
   ...> ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;
--EQP-- 0,0,0,SEARCH TABLE event USING INDEX myIdx (netAddr=? AND ID>? AND ID<?)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found that using `CREATE INDEX myIdx ON event ( netAddr );` works.

```
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN
SELECT value FROM event
WHERE netAddr = 250 AND ID > 100 AND ID < 110
ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;
```

gives

```
0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE event USING INDEX myIdx (netAddr=? AND rowid>? AND rowid<?)
```

Even it is not written anywhere in SQLite docs, rowid column in the index is kept sorted. So it is not needed to explicitly create the index `( columnXXX, rowid )` it is sufficient to create it `( columnXXX )`